# My FPS is low when I play League Of Legends

Tags: league-of-legends

I never had this problem before. I know my internet is good. I usually have 60 fps and 25 ms when I play and even when the internet is bed, it's only the ms that gets lowered nmbut never the fps.

However, when I opened my League today to play, I only got FPS as low as 08 and as high as 19 FPS which is really annoying to play with. My ms is stable though.

I did my research and maybe it's bc of my running background programs. I usually play league with windows media player active on the background so I can listen to my music and the only other program I have on is my Garena client for my LoL.

When it comes to my computer storage I only have 176gb free out of my 420gb storage. Physical memory has a total of 3943, cached: 1305, available: 2698 and my free memory is 1452. My CPU usage is only (at average) 15-18% and ny Physical Memory is at 31%.

My system processor is: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3110M CPU @ 2.40 GHz

My installed RAM is 4.00gb with only 3.85 usable.

Note: I've had this issue before but it got back to normal after a few days. I didn't do even anything.

Comment: Most of the things you listed have nothing to do with FPS. Check your video settings and open task manager to see how much of your RAM is being used. You may just need to restart your computer to close out some programs or do it manually in task manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a fellow laptop user who had some issues regarding his fps over the past few months, here are some suggestions which may eliminate the problem.

## Graphic Settings

Double check your graphical settings in League. Set everything to low, and maybe take down the resolution a bit?

## Power Plans

Power plans on Windows can control the maximum clock speed that your processor can reach. Ensure that your laptop is plugged in, and head to **Control Panel -> Hardware & Sound -> Power Options** and click the **High Performance** power plan. This will allow your processor to be clocked to its highest speed at the cost of extra power consumption (which is why you'll need to have it plugged in).

## Throttling

Laptops, especially lower-end ones, suffer from limited ventilation and the parts can easily heat up much more than their desktop variants. This heat can cause your pc to automatically down-throttle your cpu/gpu until the temperature has been lowered to a certain degree. I recommend using a CPU temp monitor, such as [Core Temp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/), and observing it while you play games.

## Background Programs & Services

Windows 10 has an odd habit of flooding your memory and disk usage with a ton of annoying background programs and services. These can affect the performance of just about any other program you're running, especially games.

1. First, I recommend using [ShutUp10](https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10) to disable many background tasks that Windows might perform.
2. Open Run (Win Key + R), type **services.msc** and hit enter or ok. Head down to **Superfetch**. Right click -> Properties, and set the Startup Type to **Disabled**.
3. While running LoL, open task manager, ensure more details are shown, and then click the CPU, Memory and Disk headings, in that order. Take note of any programs that are using a high amount of CPU/Memory/Disk. If possible, close them, though be careful not to close any system crucial programs.
4. If at all possible, get some hardware upgrades, such as more memory, or an ssd (or both if possible). Currently you have 4GBs of memory, while 8GB is highly preferred nowadays. Also, a SSD will virtually eliminate processes that tend to hog the disk usage and slow your computer down. It will also drastically minimize any load times you have across your system.

Hope that one of these will help. Lemme know how it goes.